# find last 7 days mail from gmail to csv in python

Tags: python-3.x, gmail, imap

Facing issue while extracting last 7 days email from gmail to csv by using IMAP in python. Below is the code i have built using help from blogs.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Dec  6 18:34:56 2017

@author: ravi
"""

import email, getpass, imaplib, os , datetime , csv

detach_dir = '.' # directory where to save attachments (default: current)
user = input("Enter your GMail username:")
pwd = getpass.getpass("Enter your password: ")

# connecting to the gmail imap server
m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
m.login(user,pwd)
m.select("inbox") # here you a can choose a mail box like INBOX instead
m.list()# to get all the mailboxes



date = (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(7)).strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
result, data = m.search(None, '(SENTSINCE {date})'.format(date=date))
ids = data[0]
id_list = ids.split()

final_list = [ ]


for emailid in id_list:
    temp_dict = { }
    result, data = m.fetch(id_list, "(RFC822)")# fetching the mail, "`(RFC822)`" means "get the whole stuff", but you can ask for headers only, etc
    email_body = data[0][1] # getting the mail content
    mail = email.message_from_bytes(email_body) # parsing the mail content to get a mail object
    temp_dict['Sender'] = mail["From"]
    temp_dict['Subject'] = mail["Subject"]
    temp_dict['Date'] = mail["Date"]

    print ("["+mail["From"]+"] :" + mail["Subject"] +mail["Date"])

    print (temp_dict)
    final_list.append(temp_dict)

#exporting the values as .csv
with open('CSV_NAME.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline = '') as csvfile: 
    fieldnames = ['Sender','Subject','Date']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter = ',')
    writer.writeheader()
    for val in final_list:
        writer.writerow(val)
```

In this code the data is of the type list which is not accepting the type byte. How to resolve this ?

UPDATE1:-

Tried a new piece of code. Understood what the problem is anyway to solve it?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Dec  5 19:36:33 2017

@author: ravi
"""


import email, getpass, imaplib, os , datetime , csv

detach_dir = '.' # directory where to save attachments (default: current)
user = input("Enter your GMail username:")
pwd = getpass.getpass("Enter your password: ")

# connecting to the gmail imap server
m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
m.login(user,pwd)
m.select("inbox") # here you a can choose a mail box like INBOX instead
m.list()# to get all the mailboxes



date = (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(7)).strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
resp, items = m.uid('search', None, '(SENTSINCE {date})'.format(date=date)) # you could filter using the IMAP rules here (check http://www.example-code.com/csharp/imap-search-critera.asp)
items = items[0].split() # getting the mails id

final_list = [ ]

for emailid in items:
    temp_dict = { }
    resp, data = m.uid('fetch',items,'(RFC822)')# fetching the mail, "`(RFC822)`" means "get the whole stuff", but you can ask for headers only, etc
    email_body = data[0][1] # getting the mail content
    mail = email.message_from_bytes(email_body) # parsing the mail content to get a mail object
    temp_dict['Sender'] = mail["From"]
    temp_dict['Subject'] = mail["Subject"]
    temp_dict['Date'] = mail["Date"]

    print ("["+mail["From"]+"] :" + mail["Subject"] +mail["Date"])

    print (temp_dict)
    final_list.append(temp_dict)





#exporting the values as .csv
with open('CSV_NAME.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline = '') as csvfile: 
    fieldnames = ['Sender','Subject','Date']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter = ',')
    writer.writeheader()
    for val in final_list:
        writer.writerow(val)
```

I get the error:-

```
---> 31     resp, data = m.uid('fetch',items,'(RFC822)')# fetching the mail, "`(RFC822)`" means "get the whole stuff", but you can ask for headers only, etc

\Anaconda3\lib\imaplib.py in _command(self, name, *args)
    943             if isinstance(arg, str):
    944                 arg = bytes(arg, self._encoding)
--> 945             data = data + b' ' + arg
    946 
    947         literal = self.literal
TypeError: can't concat bytes to list
```

Anyway to solve it

Answer (score 1):

`m.uid('fetch',items,'(RFC822)')`

Items cannot be a list: the imaplib commands only take strings or bytes, but items is a list of UIDs.

You'll need to massage it into a string or bytes.

I don't remember if the list results is a list of bytes or string objects, but you can get an IMAP compliant fetch list by comma separating the values.  One of these should work for you:

```
uids = ','.join(items)
uids = b','.join(items)
```

Comment: I love the laziness/helpfulness compromise.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem and I just tested everything works !

First, you need to change your ids variable to a list with only int :

```
encoding = 'utf-8'
ids = str(data[0], encoding)
```

You got a list like :

> 1 2 3 4

instead of

> b'1 2 3 4'

After that your id_list are split and give :

> ['1', '2', '3', '4']

instead of

> [b'1', b'2', b'3', b'4']

Finaly in the for you need to use emailid and not id_list. and then convert in str like that :

```py
    for emailid in id_list:
       temp_dict = { }
       result, data = m.fetch(str(emailid), "(RFC822)")
```

The result :

```py
...

encoding = 'utf-8'

...

date = (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(7)).strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
result, data = m.search(None, '(SENTSINCE {date})'.format(date=date))
ids = str(data[0], encoding)

id_list = ids.split()

final_list = [ ]

print(id_list)

for emailid in id_list:
    temp_dict = { }
    result, data = m.fetch(str(emailid), "(RFC822)")
    email_body = data[0][1]
    mail = email.message_from_bytes(email_body)
    
    temp_dict['Sender'] = mail["From"]
    temp_dict['Subject'] = mail["Subject"]
    temp_dict['Date'] = mail["Date"]

    print ("["+mail["From"]+"] :" + mail["Subject"] +mail["Date"])

    print (temp_dict)
    final_list.append(temp_dict)
```